# PHP to list files in directory, and link to them

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, directory

I know there are similar topics on the forum 
But I can not find help for my problem.

It's about connecting all the files in a directory and create a link from them.

I have a script that works, but does not perform all the way would I want a script was

```
<? php 
$ directory = "folder/folder2/folder3/ (and the file that needs to continue)"; 
$ phpfiles = glob ($ directory. "*. php"); 

foreach ($ phpfiles as $ phpfile)
{
     echo '<li> <a href="'.$phpfile.'">'. basename ($ phpfile,. "php"). '</ a> </ li>'; 
} 
?>
```

So on my site working (mod_rewrite).
Problem is that this script jug link with (php extension) 
example `http:/sitename/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.php` 
Does anyone have a suggestion with which the script to get a link without (php extension) 
example of how it should be `http:/sitename/folder1/folder2/folder3/file`

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to remove a `.php` from a string? If you can be sure it is always there you can just call

```
$string = "path/filename.php"
$string = substr($string,0,-4);
```

which should result in

```
echo $string => "path/filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Scandir to get a list of the files in a directory and then only output the ones that are a .php extention (but omitting the .php)

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
```

then

```
foreach($files as $x){
    if(substr($x,0,-4) == ".php") 
        echo '<li><a href="http://whatever.com/' . substr($x,0,-4) . '</a></li>';
}
```

Checks The extension is .php and if so, outputs the filename without the .php
I haven't done PHP in years, but I hope this helps!

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: I consider your script and reports an error that the file can not be found in the directory. 
I think it reports an error because the path of the directory. 
The problem is not solved, still need help.

Comment: C'mon dude, you can't copy and paste it and expect it to work, only you know how to integrate it. Good luck on your quest anywho.

Comment: My code should work for physical directories not logical. I can only assume now that you're asking to generate links that match that of mod_rewrite?